# How to remove Nav page-scroll underline. text-decoration: none is not working

Tags: css

I have applied

```
ul li a { text-decoration: none !important; }
```

to the entire site and the navbar links still underlines :( This is a one page site, so as you scroll the nav items highlight, but they also underline :(
Please help.

edit:
The menu items are in a list, but some of the list items are not associated with the one page, they are external links.

Comment: are you sure you haven't overridden important ? :D

Comment: what if just do this `a { text-decoration: none !important; }`?

Comment: a { text-decoration: none !important; } does not work :(

Comment: I have it on my last line of my css file, so it shouldn't be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the underlining of an anchor element you can do this:

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0cqtyzv1/)

```
a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Comment: a { text-decoration: none !important; } doesn't work  :(

Comment: @groc try clearing your cache and refreshing the page, you can also try moving this rule near the top of your CSS but make sure you are not overriding it else where. Why are you using `!important` ?

Comment: I have been compiling a bunch of onepages, into the one I want, so I have multiple css files :/  !important seems like it needs to be added, even to my last listed css file. You'd think the last listed file wouldn't need it. I haven't added import to the other css files.

Comment: @Groc you're most likely overriding the rule somewhere else, and we are unable to help you in regards to answer youring question without the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

For a one page site you Shouldn't usually have to start using !important. Once you a start using it it has a tendency to make troubleshooting difficult and you use it more and more.

Check you haven't used !important elsewhere in the CSS applying to links. If you have you'll need to ensure the rule you want to apply has a more specific selector (targeting it with an id will usually do this).

```
ul#nav li a {
    Text decoration: none !important;
}
```

I'd say try to remove the !important from the declarations and see if it still is ok.